# Isomorphism of certain irreducible representations over finite fields

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, sg.symplectic-geometry, abelian-varieties, modular-representation-theory

We are given a faithful representation of a cyclic group of order 5 $\rho: C_5=G \rightarrow End_{\mathbb{F}_3}(V) $ with $dim_{\mathbb{F}_3}V=8$ as vector space. It is also known that $V=U\oplus W$ as $\mathbb{F}_3[G]$-modules with dimension 4 as $\mathbb{F}_3$-vector spaces. Both $U$ and $W$ are irreducible representations, hence correspond to simple $\mathbb{F}_3[G]$-modules. We also know that $V$ posses a symplectic structure and that $G$ preserves the said structure, hence $G$ acts as a matrix $M\oplus (M^{-1})^T$. Furthermore, the set of their eigenvalues coincide.

Now my question is: are these two representations isomorphic? or equivalently are $\mathbb{F}_3[G]$-modules isomorphic?

Context $V$ comes as a $3$-torsion of a Jacobian of a curve of genus four and the symplectic structure comes from the Weil pairing.

Comment: The group $C_{5}$ has a (unique up to isomorphism) irreducible module over  $\mathbb{F}_{3}$, so $U$ and $W$ are isomorphic, and $U \cong U^{\ast}$. This is because the isomorphism type of a module in this context is determined up to isomorphism by its Brauer character (we first do this over the algebraic closure, and use the fact that two representations over a given field which become equivalent over an extension field are equivalent over the original field). In the case of cyclic groups knowledge of the eigenvalues of a generator is equivalent to knowledge of the Brauer character.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Thank you for your comment. What troubles me is the fact that, as vector spaces, both $U$ and $W$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{3^4}$ and are one dimensional $\mathbb{F}_{3^4}$ representations (it contains the 5th roots of unity). We have four different 1-dimensional representations with different characters. Now can't $U$, $W$ correspond to different representations with different characters? All these representations have coinciding sets of eigenvalues, but this doesn't always imply the isomorphism. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, the point is that if we extend the field to a bigger field $\mathbb{K}$ containing all $5$-th roots of unity, then $U \otimes_{\mathbb{F}} \mathbb{K}$ is a direct sum of four one dimensional $\mathbb{K}$ representations, where  each of the four primitive $5$-th roots of unity represent a fixed generator of $C_{5}$ in the four respective one-dimensional representations.

Comment: I have one last issue that deals with a certain example/possibility: it is known that if $V$ is of dimension $2g$ for odd $g$ with symplectic str, $p=2g+1$ , $l$ is a prime and $l$ mod $p$ is $g$ and $\rho: C_p \rightarrow End(V)$. Then $V=U\oplus W$ with $U$ and $W$ non-isomorphic $\mathbb{F}_l$-modules both of dimension g.  This result is known. Why your argument does not work in this case? I see that in this case, the eigenvalues do not coincide.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but here is a related example. Let $V$ be $10$-dimensional  for $C_{11}$ over $\mathbb{F}_{3}$ such that each generator of $C_{5}$ has trace $-1$ on $V$. Then $V \cong U \otimes W$, where $U$ and $W$ are irreducible modules for $C_{11}$, but $U$ and $W$ are not isomorphic - they are dual representations. On one, the eigenvalues are $\omega^{r}$ where $\omega$ is a primitive $11$-th root of unity, and $r$ runs through (non-zero) quadratic residues  (mod 11). On the other, the eigenvalues are of the form $\omega^{n}$, as $n$ runs through non-residues.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson sorry for the poorly worded comment -- and you understood my question correctly. I was not sure why in the last case of $V$ 10-dimensional $U, W$ are non-isomorphic, while in the first case they are. With the help of your last comment, I think I understand it now. Thank you so much for your comments and patience!